# scrollIntoView() not working using plain JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, scrollview

I am trying to use scrollIntoView() in order for my page to scroll to an element based on a certain condition. Here is my function:

```
  continue() {
    if (!this.data.inputs.selectedPackagingIds.length) {
      this.error = 'Please select new packaging.'; // todo translate - use translation key
    } else if (this.isPackagingSuggested && !this.data.inputs.changeReasons.filter(r => { return r.selected }).length) {
      document.getElementById("scroll-view").scrollIntoView();
      this.error = 'Please select change reason.'; // todo translate
    } else {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(LabelPrintTab, { data: this.data });
    }
  }
```

And here is my html:

```
<ion-content class="pc-nativeScannerPage">
 // Content appears in this area.
</ion-content>

<p id="scroll-view">Sentence to scroll to</p>

<ion-footer class="scroll-footer">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col text-right>
      <span *ngIf="error" class="pc-continue-error">{{Error msg goes here }} </span>
      <button (click)="continue()" class="pc-primary" ion-button>{{ This button triggers the continue() function }}</button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-footer>
```

However, nothing is happening. The page doesn't scroll to the element when this condition is true, and I can't figure out why. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I wonder if <p> tag is in a proper position or not. Why don't you put that <p> tag into the `ion-content`? Cos the element may not be scrolled completely to the top or bottom depending on the layout of other elements.

Comment: To my mind, using `scrollIntoView` is not so tricky as it's a `Working Draft` function which doesn't support cross-browser compatibility.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @RobJS I moved the <p> tag into ion-content and still having the same problem.

Comment: what if you wrap `continue()` function's content by `try~catch`? hope u could catch any errors...